# Using subprocess.run with arguments containing quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x

The command I'm trying to run looks like this:

```sh
xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24" --error-file=/dev/stdout /opt/myExecutable
```

This is what I have in Python3:

```py
args = ['xvfb-run', '--auto-servernum','--server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24"', '--error-file=/dev/stdout', '/opt/myExecutable']
command = ' '.join(xvfbArgs)
print(f'Command: {command}')
subprocess.run(xvfbArgs)
```

I get the following:

```
Unrecognized option: "-screen
use: X [:<display>] [option]
...
segfault
...
Command: xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24" --error-file=/dev/stdout /opt/myExecutable
```

The printed command is correct.

I also tried with `"-server-args='-screen 0 640x480x24'"` (inverted `"` and `'` which led to the same result (`Unrecognized option: '-screen`)

What goes on in `subprocess.run` that changes `--server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24"`?

Comment: `--server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24"` in bash is **exactly** equivalent to `"--server-args=-screen 0 640x480x24"`. The quotes are bash syntax evaluated on a character-by-character basis, not data to pass to `xvfb-run`, so you shouldn't be putting *any* literal quotes in the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct syntax would be:

```
args = [
    'xvfb-run',
    '--auto-servernum',
    '--server-args=-screen 0 640x480x24',
    '--error-file=/dev/stdout',
    '/opt/myExecutable'
]

try:
    from pipes import quote  # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from shlex import quote  # Python 3

command_str = ' '.join(quote(s) for s in args)
print(f'Command: {command_str}')

subprocess.run(args) # or subprocess.run(command_str, shell=True)
```

Note that there are *no* literal quotes here at all -- the only quotes are Python syntax. In bash, unescaped quotes are syntax, not data, even when they exist part of the way through a string.

Comment: The OP proceeds to merge the arguments into a single string so they do need some quotes after all. But of course, a much better solution is to just keep the arguments as a list.

Comment: They're merging into a string for the sake of *printing to the user*. Better to use `shlex.quote()` for that job, to generate content in the same format expected by a shell.

Comment: @tripleee I merged into an array to see what the command to run would be. I missed the part where `subprocess.run` would quote my argument because there was a space in it.

Comment: @Nepoxx, what do you mean, "quote my argument"? If you pass a list of strings to `subprocess.Popen` with `shell=False`, those strings become the array of C strings passed to the `execve` syscall. They're *literal* strings, so no quoting is used or needed at the OS level.

Comment: @Nepoxx, ...that is to say, when you run `xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24"` in bash, it becomes an array of pointers to C strings, something that might also be described as `char**{"xvfb-run", "--server-args=-screen 0 640x480x24", NULL}` -- there are no quotes anywhere in any of those strings; the quotes were consumed and removed by the shell when it took them to mean that `640x480x24` should be in the same argument as `--server-args=`.

Comment: I assumed that from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) "Providing a sequence of arguments is generally preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file names)."

Comment: @Nepoxx, "any required escaping" leaves open the possibility that on some platforms (aka *all* non-Windows systems) no escaping is in fact required. See `man 2 execve` for the manual of the underlying set of operating-system calls.

Answer (score 4):

Just don't merge the command into a string, and then don't put quotes where they were in place to protect a string from the shell.

```
args = ['xvfb-run', '--auto-servernum','--server-args=-screen 0 640x480x24', '--error-file=/dev/stdout', '/opt/myExecutable']
print(f'Command: {args}')
subprocess.run(args)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple way to tell what the command you pass to `subprocess.run` should look like. In the shell (not Python, a regular shell), insert `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])'` before the command you want to run:

```
19:59 ~ $ python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv[1:])' xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24" --error-file=/dev/stdout /opt/myExecutable
['xvfb-run', '--auto-servernum', '--server-args=-screen 0 640x480x24', '--error-file=/dev/stdout', '/opt/myExecutable']
```

The resulting list is *exactly* what you should pass to `subprocess.run`. Here, we can see that the shell converted the `--server-args="-screen 0 640x480x24"` in the input into a single argument with no quotes in it.